# Increase time to typing and find an element in JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist, jcomponent

I have a JList and this component has a lot of items.
If I type some text, an element was selected.

For example, if I have this elements:

1. element1
2. initialElement
3. lastElement
4. partElement
5. poorElement
6. overElement

And if I enter "p", the "partElement" was selected.
If I enter "po", the "poorElement" was selected.

But I have a time to type the element. If I type very slowly, the element that I want is not found. For example, If I type "po" slowly, the element "overElement" was selected.

I need to increase the time that the user can enter a text to find an element. It can be possible? How can I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to change this by using the UIManager:

```
UIManager.put("List.timeFactor", new Long(2000));
```

The default in the `BasicListUI` if there is no `List.timeFactor` default is 1000.

Properties of the UIManager should be set before you create your components.

Comment: Thank you. Now, if the type is an error, the time still enable. Do you know how can I inicialize the time if the element was not found?

Comment: @computered, glad the suggestion help. The code in BasicListUI doesn't differentiate between found/not found. All the code does is determine if the type character should be appended to the previous string, or not.

Comment: Can I differentiate the time for found/not found? If the element not found, I need to wait the time finish, and Its not good.

Comment: @computered, you need to override the default code and create a custom UI. I don't know how to do this.